# Low fps in scene/game window in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sometimes i have low fps in scene/game window when i click Play button. Here is screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRuhH.png)

This happens rarely, but still no pleasure to see this 2 fps, where it should be 150fps at least. Screenshot of high framerate - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu9fY.png)
Any thoughts how to fix this?

Profiler screenshot - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI2yJ.png)

Comment: This is a very broad question, lots of details are needed. I suggest studying this https://learn.unity.com/course/performance-and-optimisation

Comment: I don't think that it's because of unity. Are there any background tasks running?

Comment: @YGreater only discord and browser.

Comment: I don't mean apps opened. Open task manager and see if any task is eating CPU or ram. But as already mentioned in answer it can be light baking real-time. Also it could be they there are too many materials or too heavy materials are being rendered in a scene and you get 2 fps because of that. Удачи Тёма!

Comment: No lights in scene, in hierarchy only few 2D objects. When fps = 2, i have 80%+ of RAM usage as task manager shows (Unity project eats the biggest part). CPU is okay. Btw, i have pathfinding scripts in 2D enemy objects. Fps starts falling only when these objects are in scene, but i already asked developer of this pathfinding script and he told that the script is working okay, but something throws a lot of exceptions. I added a profiler screenshot above.